# How to disable div transition until ok is clicked in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) Noty plugin.

The plugin shows up when `onPageLoad` event is fired, and tells you to hover the header `<div>`.

Hovever, the `Noty` is positioned right underneath it. If you hover the header `<div>`, it expands, leaving the `Noty` on the top. It looks like a mess.

With `z-index` I could get it stay down, but it's not what I want.
I need to disable `header:hover` to be disabled until you confirm the `Noty`.
It's impossible to make it work on <kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.com)</kbd>, but here's the code near to main:

### CSS:

```css
.header {
    overflow: hidden;
    background:#FFF;
    border-bottom:1px solid gray;
    box-shadow:0 0 10px;
    height:70px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    width:100%;
    z-index:2;
    background: rgb(210,255,82); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(210,255,82,1) 0%, rgba(145,232,66,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(210,255,82,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(145,232,66,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(210,255,82,1) 0%,rgba(145,232,66,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(210,255,82,1) 0%,rgba(145,232,66,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(210,255,82,1) 0%,rgba(145,232,66,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(210,255,82,1) 0%,rgba(145,232,66,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#d2ff52', endColorstr='#91e842',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    transition: height 0.8s ease;
    transition-delay: 1s;
}

.header:hover {
    height: 120px;
    transition: height 0.8s ease;
}

.noty {
  top: 70px;
  position: relative;
}
```

### HTML

```html
<div class="header">
  <img src="artotek_ico.gif" height="70px" style="padding-bottom: 10px;" />
  <span class="kielet">
    <nav>

    <!--Englanti-->
    <a href="en_index.html" title="Englanniksi">In English</a>

    <!--Ruotsi-->
    <a href="swe_index.html" title="Ruotsiksi">På Svenska</a>

    <!--Venäjä-->
    <a href="ru_index.html" title="Venäjäksi">По русски</a>
  </span>
 </div>

 <div class="noty">
<!--jQuery Plugins Declarations-->

     </div>
```

### JavaScript

```js
var n = noty()
};

function generate(layout) {
    var n = noty({
        text: layout,
        type: 'information',
        text: 'Change your language here! Dismiss this by clicking.',
      dismissQueue: true,
        layout: layout,
        theme: 'defaultTheme'
    });
    console.log('html: '+n.options.id);
  }

  function generateAll() {
    generate('top');
    generate('topCenter');
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {

        generateAll();

  });

  $.noty.top = {
    layout: 'top',
    theme: 'defaultTheme',
    type: 'information',
    text: '',
    dismissQueue: true, // If you want to use queue feature set this true
    template: '<div class="noty_message"><span class="noty_text"></span><div class="noty_close"></div></div>',
    animation: {
        open: {height: 'toggle'},
        close: {height: 'toggle'},
        easing: 'swing',
        speed: 500 // opening & closing animation speed
    },
    timeout: 500, // delay for closing event. Set false for sticky notifications
    force: false, // adds notification to the beginning of queue when set to true
    modal: false,
    maxVisible: 5, // you can set max visible notification for dismissQueue true option
    closeWith: ['click'], // ['click', 'button', 'hover']
    callback: {
        onShow: function() {},
        afterShow: function() {},
        onClose: function() {},
        afterClose: function() {}
    },
    buttons: false // an array of buttons
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the header's hover class to this:

```
.header.enabled:hover {
    height: 120px;
    transition: height 0.8s ease;
}
```

This will limit the CSS :hover style to when `.header` also has the class `enabled`.

Then add or remove the class `enabled` on `.header` in the appropriate noty callbacks, e.g.

```
onShow: function() { $(".header").removeClass("enabled"); },
onClose: function() { $(".header").addClass("enabled"); },
```

Comment: Thanks, I might just get it. Where do I add the Noty callbacks? Sorry I'm a total noob in JS :)

Comment: In your fiddle your JS is full of syntax errors. Check your browser's developer tools javascript console to see what they are. As a heads up, you are missing the closing `}` for the end of your `afterClose` callback, `buttons: false // an array of buttons` has been put outside of the noty options and needs moving, in `afterClose` callback you are missing a `(` in `$ ".header")`. Please read your code carefully. See http://jsfiddle.net/4B8Yc/1/ for help, but I will not continue to fix basic syntax errors for you! ;)